# jquery touchgallery display image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, gallery

how can i display the link of the image wich was clicked in the document?

i've added a class to the image when the image was clicked that works fine but when i want to display the image where the class was added with getelementbyid it doesn't find it and in the source code it is not visible.

please help me!!

**EDIT:**

above i wrote class but i took the id!

i have an website which is displayed on the iphone in my app. on the site is a gallery and in xcode i get the image with getelementbyid('download_fullscreen'). so when the image is tapped it goes fullscreen but this is generated by jquery with the plugin touchgallery i can assign an id to the clicked image but it is not recognized in the app on the iphone. and when i slide to the next image the id will not move to the next image. here is the demo: http://neteye.github.com/touch-gallery.html when you click on an image it will be fullscreen and the gallerycode is generated by javascript. how can i print the imageurl from the image which is currently in fullscreen to the document that my iphone app can recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

getElementByID will return object only if you are assigning ID to tag and not CLASS.

For eg. getElementByID will work here as ID is assigned with tag

`<img id="myid" class="clicked" src="your_image_path">`

But not in this case.

`<img class="clicked" src="your_image_path">`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you've added a class to an `<img>` tag, and you're able to select the image element, via `document.getElementById()` or otherwise ([`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/document.getelementsbyclassname)), you can get the element's `src` attribute easily:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
var imageUrl = myImage.src;
```

Regrettably, this only gains you a relative path. Hopefully the URLs are absolute, otherwise you'll need to handle them. Hope this helps a little!
Check out: ["HTMLImageElement at MDC"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Image)